# Setting values of an array without a loop

Tags: python, arrays

I have arrays called `rad`, `relative_x`, `relative_y`, where `rad` is not of the same size as the other two. I want to create an array called `masking`, that will have the length of `rad` in the following way:

```
masking[i] = (relative_x**2 + relative_y**2 <= (rad[i])**2) & (relative_x**2 + relative_y**2 >= (rad[i]*0.9)**2)
```

but I want to do it without a loop. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: First, a loop will occur anyway, even if you'll use list comprehension.   Second, how are you planning on doing it if the arrays have different length?

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` and a list comprehension pretty much does it. You still have a loop, but it's somewhat hidden.

```
>>> rad = [1.42, 4, 8]
>>> relative_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> relative_y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> 
>>> masking = [rad_**2 >= relative_x_**2 + relative_y_**2 >= (rad_*0.9)**2
               for (rad_, relative_x_, relative_y_) in zip(rad, relative_x, relative_y)]
>>> print masking
[True, False, False]
```

Note that in python, you're allowed to do `1 < 2 < 3`.